# React app creation: create-react-app doesn't have any effect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm trying to create a React application using create-react-app.

Whenever I run the command, nothing happens (no effect in console and no files created):
[image: create.react.app no effect]

I tried to reinstall npm, update node, clean cache, and other things.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: what is version of your nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

have you install npm correctly?

please check npm in command line

```
npm
```

version should appear

```
npm <command>

Usage:

npm install        install all the dependencies in your project
npm install <foo>  add the <foo> dependency to your project
npm test           run this project's tests
npm run <foo>      run the script named <foo>
npm <command> -h   quick help on <command>
npm -l             display usage info for all commands
npm help <term>    search for help on <term>
npm help npm       more involved overview

All commands:

    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, cache, ci, completion,
    config, dedupe, deprecate, diff, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, exec, explain, explore, find-dupes, fund, get, help,
    hook, init, install, install-ci-test, install-test, link,
    ll, login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping,
    pkg, prefix, profile, prune, publish, rebuild, repo,
    restart, root, run-script, search, set, set-script,
    shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, team, test, token,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, update, version, view, whoami

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /Users/peter.lam/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key=value

More configuration info: npm help config
Configuration fields: npm help 7 config

npm@8.11.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Comment: It's installed already, I checked everything many times..

Comment: copy paste that  npm i -g npx

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** `'npm cache clean --force'` **command before you create a react app**

Comment: I tried, but nothing happened like before..

Comment: before creating app try this command 'npm cache clean --force'

Comment: NPM cache almost never requires clearing. Also, it doesn't solve the issue OP has

Comment: oh okey then what is the issue here why he is not able to create a react-app

Answer (score 0):

Please read documents and try to follow steps provided in this document 
[React Native Create App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

1 - Install Node JS 
2 - Check Node version using `node -v` if return any version then Node JS installed correctly  
3 - Then try to create your react js app by following commands

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Comment: I did follow it even before, I have everything installed. I searched a lot for my problem, but I can't find it anywhere else..

Comment: Can you please post your node version , if it is latest version then please try older version

Answer (score -1):

it's

```
npm create react-app <your-app-name>
```

if you'd like to use a typescript template, then, it's

```
npm create react-app <your-app-name> --template typescript
```